# UITextView Links Highlighted but Safari not launched

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am trying to implement clickable URLs on iOS. I looked at all the posts on SO and did the following for my `TextView` after I am done building it and adding the text:

```
    self.messageLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.messageLabel.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    self.messageLabel.scrollEnabled=NO;
    self.messageLabel.editable=NO;
    self.messageLabel.selectable=YES;
    self.messageLabel.delegate=self;
```

I also implemented `(TextView*)textview shouldInteractWithURL:` etc...

Maybe the problem is my `TextView` is nested inside a `UIView` which is itself `subview` of my custom `UITableCell`.

The links show correctly and are highlighted in blue. When I click on them, they flicker, but Safari is not launched and the delegate method is not called. Just to confirm, I am properly adding the protocol `UITextViewDelegate` and setting `messageLabel.delegate` to the cell.

Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe u set your `messageLabel.delegate` to wrong place, result in the `shouldInteractWithURL ` is not called.. or u didnt link the iboutlet, i did the same as u in a very complicated cell it still work fine

Comment: Actually I read in the docs that implementing shouldInteractWithURL is optional. If I remove it, it should automatically open the link. So the problem seems to be with the links...

Comment: well but if u put delegate like that...it should be called right....even if its incorrect link still it should be open in safary, maybe u can just check the detect link in storyboard and remove everything else related in code and see

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The problem was indeed that my UITextView was nested inside an intermediary UIView. I just made it a direct subView of the UITableViewCell and it now works perfectly!

Thanks all for looking at this.